# Android emulator Gingerbread x86 Google APIs missing

Tags: android-emulator, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to install the system image for Android emulators versioned lower than 4.x.

I have installed the L and M emulators with Google APIs just fine, but when I download for example the Gingerbread Google API emulator, it just disappears after download. After I download the image it's missing from both the intalled and downloadable system images. Any idea why this might be? I'm seeing this on both stable 1.5.1 and 2.0 preview 4.

Image below, Gingerbread GAPI images missing from downloadables list.

[image: Ginger Google API images missing from downloadables]

Image below, Gingerbread GAPI images missing from installed list.

[image: Ginger Google API images also missing from installed images]